# Optimising three LEFT JOIN in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

My issue is to optimize using Left Join
I have 4 Tables:

```
1.Main 
2.City
3.Country
4.Area
```

Structure of table:

1. Main

   - Origin_City - Dest_City
   - Origin_Country - Dest_Country
   - Orig_Area - Dest_Area
2. City

   - Origin_City - Dest_City
   - Origin_Country - Dest_Country
   - Orig_Area - Dest_Area
   - Value_City
3. Country

   - Origin_Country - Dest_Country
   - Orig_Area - Dest_Area
   - Value_Country
4. Area

   - Orig_Area - Dest_Area
   - Value_Area

Main table has to be compared with three tables to get the values.

1. when **Origin_city** and **Dest_city** of main table exactly matches with **Origin_city** and **Dest_City** of City table, then **Value_City** from City table is considered.
2. If **Orig_city** and **Dest_city** of Main table does not matches with City table(when **Value_City** is not available). Then **Origin_Country** and **Dest_Country** of Main table is compared with Country table, if it matches, then **Value_Country** is considered.
3. If **Origin_Country** and **Dest_Country** does not matches with the Country table. Then **Origin_Area** and **Dest_Area** of the Main table is compared with Area table, if it matches then **Value_Area** is considered.

I have written a MySQL query according to the requirement. The issue is City table has nearly 1 million rows and it takes huge time to run. 
My code is below

```
SELECT main.Origin_City, main.Dest_City,
main.Origin_Country, main.Dest_Country,
main.Origin_Area, main.Dest_Area,
IFNULL(Value_City,IFNULL(Value_Country,Value_Area))

FROM main
LEFT JOIN City 
on (main.Origin_City = City.Origin_City) 
   and (main.Dest_City = City.Dest_City)

LEFT JOIN Country 
ON (main.Origin_Country = Country.Origin_Country) 
   and (main.Dest_Country = Country.Dest_Country)

LEFT JOIN Area 
ON (main.Origin_Area = Area.Origin_Area) and (main.Dest_Area = Area.Dest_Area)
```

1. I also wrote the queries using where clause and Case Statement. It also takes huge time to run.
2. I extracted the Country and Area tables from city table. There are many values available for particular Country and I take `MIN` value from that.

How can I optimize the query, to get result. I recently started querying in MySQL. I did same thing in MS Access. It works perfect.

Comment: how many rows have the other tables?

Comment: City is 130,000 and Area is 700 around

Comment: Do your tables have any indexes?

Comment: No index. The Main table and other City, Country and Area tables are totally different.

Comment: If you want to join these tables and you have ~1M records, you should really consider using indexes for the columns which you use to join the tables. Give it a try... It will probably solve your performance issue. If you recently started querying in MySQL, you are on the right track with the query.

Comment: @Ip_ thanks for suggesting about indexes, I am working on it, how to make tables with indexes. It is possible to make index for City, Country and Area. But Main table is totally different.